# Change value of tag attibute?

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the value of the `readonly` attribute using jQuery but this piece of code does not work :

```
$('#L1E').live('change',function() {
  $('.hidden').attr('readonly',''); 
  return false;  
});
```

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: In both case you're setting the value to ''.

Comment: and you're storing the alerted value before you change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use removeAttr to remove the read only attribute:

```
$('.hidden').removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using .on (jQuery 1.7+) delegation instead of .live since .live() has been deprecated.  You should also use the .prop (jQuery 1.6+) method to set the readonly property

```
$('body').on('change','#L1E', function() {
    v = $('.hidden').prop('readonly')
    if (v) {
        $('.hidden').prop('readonly', false);
        alert(v);
    }
    else {
        $('.hidden').prop('readonly', true);
        alert(v);
    }    
    return false;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rMnx3/